# Monitoring a few servers / API endpoints

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create a simple NodeJS program that monitors few provided servers or machines and provides output in JSON.

```js
// @file name : watch.js
// author : Abhinav Gauniyal

// requires

var os = require('os');
var http = require('http');
var net = require('net');
var diskspace = require('diskspace');

var s = net.Socket();

// variables - declares and default values

var machineName = "MyMachine" + (Math.floor(Math.random() * (9000 - 2000)) + 2000); // generate random name for fallback
var address = '127.0.0.1'; // localhost
var portnum = 4444; // default port num for socket communication

// calculate static values
var hostName = os.hostname();
var hostPlatform = os.platform();
var hostArch = os.arch();
var hostRelease = os.release();

// will later use
var jsonString;
var dataToTransmit = [];
var spaceArray = [];
var mountPoint = '/';

// functions

// reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900485/correct-way-to-convert-size-in-bytes-to-kb-mb-gb-in-javascript
function bToS(bytes) {
    if (bytes === 0) return '0 Byte';
    var k = 1000;
    var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'];
    var i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k));
    return (bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toPrecision(3) + ' ' + sizes[i];
}

diskspace.check(mountPoint, function(err, total, free, status) {
    spaceArray = [bToS(total), bToS(free), status];
});

function declare(name, addr, port, mtpt) {
    machineName = name;
    address = addr;
    portnum = port;
    mountPoint = mtpt;
}

function collectNow() {
    var hostInfo = {
        machineName: machineName,
        address: address,
        portnum: portnum,
        name: hostName,
        platform: hostPlatform,
        arch: hostArch,
        release: hostRelease,
        space: spaceArray,
        cpus: os.cpus(),
        metrics: {
            Uptime: os.uptime(),
            TotalMem: bToS(os.totalmem()),
            FreeMem: bToS(os.freemem())
        }
    };
    return hostInfo;
}


function connect(delay) {
    jsonString = JSON.stringify(collectNow());
    s.connect(portnum);
    s.write(jsonString);
    s.end();
    setTimeout(function() {
        connect(delay);
    }, delay);
}


function updateDataWith(parsedData) {
    if (dataToTransmit.length === 0) {
        dataToTransmit.push(parsedData);
    } else {
        var isPresent = false;
        var location = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < dataToTransmit.length; ++i) {
            if (dataToTransmit[i].machineName == parsedData.machineName) {
                isPresent = true;
                location = i;
            } else continue;
        }
        if (isPresent) {
            dataToTransmit[location] = parsedData;
        } else {
            dataToTransmit.push(parsedData);
        }
    }
}

// create server

function watchAt(port1, port2) {

    // create socket

    net.createServer(function(socket) {

        socket.on('data', function(data) {
            var parsedData = JSON.parse(data.toString());
            updateDataWith(parsedData);

        });
    }).listen(port1);
    console.log("Socket is active at port" + port1 + ", transmitting data to server.");

    // create server

    http.createServer(function(req, res) {

        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.end(JSON.stringify(dataToTransmit));

    }).listen(port2);
    console.log("Server is active , check json output on http://localhost:" + port2 + "/");
}


exports.connect = connect;
exports.declare = declare;
exports.watchAt = watchAt;


// ====================================================
// start server as :
// ....................................................
// var s = require('watch');
// s.watchAt(4444, 8888);
// ....................................................
// ----------------------------------------------------
//
// ----------------------------------------------------
// connect client as :
// ....................................................
// var w = require('watch');
// w.declare("MyMachine#1", '127.0.0.1', 4000,'/home');
// w.connect(3000);
// ....................................................
// but not inside your server loop or any loop
// ====================================================
```

For starting a server:

```js
// watch.js server

var s = require('./watch');
s.watchAt(4444, 8888);
```

A new client:

```js
var w = require('./watch');

// do something here

w.declare("MyMachine#1", '127.0.0.1', 4444, '/');
w.connect(3000);
```

It works by creating a HTTP server on specified port, and another websocket server. Data are calculated by function `collectNow()` and `diskspace` and prettyfied by `bToS()`. Then every possible variable is initialized as I have no idea how JS handles creation and destroying of variables (coming from RAII). And at last client connects and sends all data in string format which is again converted into JSON to view in browser.

I'm new to JS/Nodejs and this whole asynchronous thing, so I might've overlooked a few things, plus I could be doing something wrong so I'm looking for feedback.

Comment: For now I've no idea how to go on about benchmarking this program. All I could see was htop giving 0.6% ram usage for about 15 mins.

Comment: Benchmarking this for memory usage is useless (as long as it is written in a sane manner); memory usage is very rarely a limiting factor in Node and if it does become a factor you are probably using node incorrectly

Comment: @DanPantry thankyou for providing that insight , are there any blogs or good articles about benchmarking , profiling nodejs programs?